# Jinja & Wtforms- check if html attribute has been defined

Tags: html, for-loop, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

Let's say I have a form with a hundred fields. Some of them have `description` defined:

i.e. `Sales=IntegerField('Sales', description='Annual Sales')`

some of them do not:

i.e. `Name=TextField('Full Name')`

in Jinja, how can I check whether `description` has been set or not?

I've tried

```
{% for field in form %}
{% if field.description != None %}
<h2>{{field.description}}</h2>
    {{field.label}}
    {{field}}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm trying to iterate through the fields, and create an html header to group the fields into sections.

I was also doing

```
{%set currDesc="nothing"%}
{%for field in form %}
  {% if field.description != currDesc %}
      <h2>{{field.description}}</h2>
      {% set currDesc= field.description %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

but it ends up creating a ton of `<h2>`s

Answer (score 0):

upon further research, we can check whether an attribute is defined explicitly in wtforms by using an empty string comparison:

```
{% if field.description =! '' %}
  <h2>{{field.description}}</h2>
{% endif %}
```